# Multi user application through multi terminals

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Night people,

I have what I believe to be a simple problem, but can't figure out how to solve it:

I want to create a multi-thread multi-user application which will be launched in the same computer through multiple terminals, a game for example.

The application should be executed through the terminal like

```
./foo
```

And after 3, for example, terminals have called this then the game should begin:

Terminal 1:

```
./foo
Waiting for other users...
```

Terminal 2:

```
./foo
Waiting for other users...
```

Terminal 3:

```
./foo
Starting...
```

I just don't see a mechanism to do that once each time I call ./foo from a terminal it creates another process. How can I make it "count" how many times it was called instead of creating another process? If there is another approach (and probably there is), which one?

Answer (score 1):

There is not, every time you launch it again you will be creating a new process, but you can make the program create a unix socket, and then all the next ones will connect to the same socket and communicate with each other in some way defined by you.

Comment: Right. Or pass some parameter to launch the program in _server mode_ and then one of the players will launch the server independently of the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for InterProcessCommunication: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/

There are multiple techniques to do this:

- Pipes
- Message Queues
- Shared Memory
- Sockets

Consult the Guide for examples to each technique.